# Date translation in logstash for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We have following date in CSV

AccountingTimeStamp

2020-04-26+10:43:21.8

How can I translate it to elasticsearch date with logstash ?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use the `date` filter, take a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html). Is this time in UTC or you are on a different Timezone? You will need to specify that, elasticsearch only store dates in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Match filter:

An array with field name first, and format patterns following, [ field,
formats... ]

If your time field has multiple possible formats, you can do this:

```
    match => [ "logdate", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",
          "MMM  d yyyy HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
```

The above will match a syslog (rfc3164) or iso8601 timestamp.

All you have to do is to put your format instead of one of the above.

You can read about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match)

Comment: good to hear!  I will appreciate if you could upvote and mark as answered.
@lleon596